# Is there an easy way to skip any errors when converting objects to int in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have, what are essentially IDs in a field named 'Site'.  These are in a dataframe as an object type.  I tried to convert them to type int, so I can join to another dataframe that has type int for ID.

I tried the following lines and got conversion errors.

```
df_nat['Site'] = df_nat['Site'].astype(str).astype(float)
df_nat['Site'] = df_nat.Site.astype(int)
```

I really don't care if a few 'Site' records are not converted, because these will just fall off when I do the join between the two dataframes, and that's fine.  I just want to get the ones that should be converted, converted.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the code in a `try`/`except` block?

Comment: Use `pd.to_numeric`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in this way:

```
try:
    df_nat['Site'] = df_nat['Site'].astype(str).astype(float)
    df_nat['Site'] = df_nat.Site.astype(int)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

when some error it will print the couse and will not break the code.

in a loop instance:

```
for df_nat in results:
    try:
        df_nat['Site'] = df_nat['Site'].astype(str).astype(float)
        df_nat['Site'] = df_nat.Site.astype(int)
    except Exception as e:
        continue
```

`continue` will skill the loop to next loop

Comment: This works.  I thought of this before posting, but In thought there was some kind of 'coerce' syntax that would force it to skip bad records.  Anyway, thanks for the assist.  Not sure why I got 3 down-votes.  This is a legitimate thing.

Comment: you can do a try except in loops i will add example

Comment: I just figured out another way to get what I need:

df_nat = df_nat[df_nat.Site.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]